# Determine min and max in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, max, min

I am new to gnuplot and i am trying to determine the mina nd max from a datafile and afterwards plot the data

So far I have managed to determine the min and max like this:

```
# Define two helper functions
ismin(x) = (x<min)?min=x:0
ismax(x) = (x>max)?max=x:0

# Initialise the 'global' vars
max=-1e38
min=1e38

plot "Data.txt" u 0:(ismin($3)*ismax($3))
```

The problem is that I am trying to plot the data using splot, and it's not working.

I am trying this:

```
splot \
'Data.txt' u 2:1:3 with pm3d t '',\
```

If I remove the part related to determining the min and max, the splot command works.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gnuplot: max and min values in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580236/gnuplot-max-and-min-values-in-a-range)

Answer (score 25):

Look into the `stats` command:

```
stats 'datafile' using 3
```

for example, will get statistics on the 3rd column (z data), and store them in variables (`STATS_min` and `STATS_max` may be what you want).  To see all the variables created, type

```
show variables all
```

after running `stats`.  If you have an older version of gnuplot without `stats`, you can plot the file without creating an output, and gnuplot automatically defines some `DATA_`-prefixed variables including a min/max.  The `stats` command saves the trouble of defining a null output to get data before plotting.

Comment: great  .. thanks ... I was looking for this one .. Gnuplot 4.6 has added some really really great features ...