# undefined variable: GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN (Gnuplot)

Tags: gnuplot

Based on this post (I am using gnuplot gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 1):

[gnuplot: max and min values in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580236/gnuplot-max-and-min-values-in-a-range)

I am trying to use `set yr [GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX]` in my .pg script that plots data from this .dat file:

```
100 2
200 4
300 9
```

But I get:

```
undefined variable: GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN
```

This is my script:

```
set terminal png
set output 'img.png'
set xlabel 'x-label'
set ylabel 'y-label'
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
set yrange [GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX]
plot 'sample.dat' with boxes title ""
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gnuplot-defined variables are available only after a `plot` command (In the question you linked to, a `replot` is used to plot again).

Basically you have different options:

1. First plot to terminal `unknown`, and then change to the real terminal, set the range (now the variables are available), and `replot`:

   ```
   set xlabel 'x-label'
   set ylabel 'y-label'
   set boxwidth 0.5 relative
   set style fill solid

   set terminal unknown
   plot 'sample.dat' with boxes title ""

   set terminal pngcairo
   set output 'img.png'
   set yrange [GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX]
   replot
   ```

   Note, that I used the `pngcairo` terminal, which gives much better results, than the `png` terminal. And I used `set boxwidth 0.5 relative`.
2. Use `set autoscale` to fix the ranges instead of setting an explicit `yrange`. You can use `set offset` to specify a margin based on the autoscaled values:

   ```
   set autoscale yfix
   # set offset 0,0,0.5,0.5
   plot 'sample.dat' with boxes title ''
   ```
3. Use the `stats` command to extract the minimum and maximum values:

   ```
   stats 'sample.dat' using 1:2
   set yrange[STATS_min_y:STATS_max_y]
   plot 'sample.dat' with boxes title ''
   ```