# Gnuplot - yrange - scaling only max parameter

Tags: gnuplot

I have data that is in a yrange <-100 ; 100>
I want to plot data from 60 to max, but the maximum must me autoscaled.

I tried `set yrange [60:*]` or `[60:]` but it report message: all points y value undefined!
If I change value under `14`, `[13:*]` it work and write me message: empty y range [13:13], adjusting to [13:13.13]

Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: That should work. Put a `reset` before your commands to make sure you have no odd settings. What about the simplest command like `reset; set yrange [60:*]; plot 'data.txt'`, does it work? If not, please post a *short* script and possibly upload your data file, or parts of it somewhere.

Comment: I tried insert the command reset to the GNU_HEAD var.
But it still doest not work. Here is a part of code where I build header of gnuplot parameters.
http://pastebin.com/wxpjnGKT
For explanation: ARR_YMIN_YMAX is calculated y min max values using awk. So If I insert parameters -y 80 (PRM_YMIN) and -Y auto (PRM_YMAX)
than the script generate "set yrange [80:*]".
There is a data file:
http://pastebin.com/iKJsd9tc

Comment: Its quite hard to debug such a script. With your data the following raw gnuplot script works fine: `reset; set timefmt '[%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S]'; set xdata time; set yrange [60:*]; plot 'sin_day_int.data' using 1:3`. Why do you need to calculate the min and max data with awk? If you want tight fitting e.g. of the xrange to the data range, use `set autoscale xfix`.

Comment: Thanks for advices.Using this script a generate a video from images and if I use -X max (obtained using awk) get 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lswEpnYTM4

If I use set autoscale xfixmax, get this:
http://youtu.be/jDGzf9BWsMg

Comment: I tried to run following commands in gnuplot:
set timefmt "[%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S]"
set xdata time
set xrange ["[2009/05/11 07:57:00]":"[2009/05/12 07:20:00]"]
set yrange [-9900:9900]
set autoscale ymin
set autoscale ymax
plot 'dataEdux/big.data' using 1:3

and it works, but if i run script i have this output:
(difference is that i process data file piece by piece)
there is output from gnuplot
http://pastebin.com/xYaLgqZ6
If i delete "set autoscale ymin
set autoscale ymax" so it work but withou auto scalying y range.
data file (http://pastebin.com/gezFfe6b)

Comment: What is `set -n 1,8p big.file` supposed to do? For me it returns nothing, which would explain why the error message.

Comment: So the problem has been resolved. If I set a xranges with these values  ["[2009/05/11 07:57:00]":"[2009/05/12 07:20:00]"] and i wanted to plot data out of this range.. so the gnuplot alerted me. As a result I found the first occurence with this value: [2009/05/11 07:57:00] and plot from this line <sed FOUNDED_LINE,...
Thank you very much for your help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX variable or the stats command could be helpful?  See [gnuplot: max and min values in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580236/gnuplot-max-and-min-values-in-a-range?rq=1)

Comment: Gnuplot provides so many options for autoscaling, no need for `stats` or similar...