# Can I pad a plot in Chart::Gnuplot (Perl)?

Tags: perl, plot, charts, gnuplot

I am creating a graph with Chart::Gnuplot in Perl. When I have data points on the extreme edges of the plot area, they are difficult to see against the black plot border:

[image: plot without padding]

(Can you see the plot points on the edge at (0,3) and (0,4)?)

Is there a way to pad the plot area with whitespace so that plot points on the edges of the graph are offset from the plot border?

Instead of this:

```
----------
|  +     +
+        |
|     +  |
----------
```

...I want it to look more like this:

```
--------------
|    +     + |
| +          |
|       +    |
--------------
```

Comment: Can't you make the x axis a bit wider, [-1, 2] instead of [0, 1]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [offsets](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf#page145):

> Offsets provide a mechanism to put an empty boundary around the data inside an autoscaled graph. The offsets only affect the x1 and y1 axes, and only in 2D ‘plot‘ commands.
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> set offsets <left>, <right>, <top>, <bottom>
> unset offsets
> show offsets
> ```
>
> Each offset may be a constant or an expression. Each defaults to 0. By default, the left and right offsets are given in units of the first x axis, the top and bottom offsets in units of the first y axis. Alternatively, you may specify the offsets as a fraction of the total axis range by using the keyword "graph".

The following adds a 10% offset to each axis:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Chart::Gnuplot;

my @x = (0, 0, 1);
my @y = (3, 4, 10);

my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    output  => 'gnuplot.png',
    xrange  => [0, 1],
    yrange  => [0, 10],
    offsets => 'graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1, graph 0.1'
);

my $dataset = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    xdata => \@x,
    ydata => \@y
);

$chart->plot2d($dataset);
```

(`Chart::Gnuplot` doesn't have an `offsets` option, but if you supply an option that it doesn't recognize, it simply [converts it](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chart::Gnuplot#Chart-Options-Not-Mentioned-Above) to a Gnuplot `set` statement.)

#### Output:

[image: plot with offsets]

Comment: This works for the most part, but it adds an additional tic on each edge of the graph. Originally I had x and y tics start at 0, but with the offset option, they start at -1, which is ugly. Can I turn off those -1 tics somehow, or can I just have `offsets` add white space instead of actual tic values?

Comment: @Ben If you expand the range of your axes, naturally you will get more tics. You can use the [`xtics` and `ytics`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Chart::Gnuplot#xtics-ytics-ztics) options to manually set the range where tics are shown.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that fixes the problem. My xrange is set to [0, '*'], and my yrange is [0, 10]. The offset apparently expands that range, so if I change the ranges to [1, '\*'] and [1, 9] respectively, I'm back where I was before using offset, with no padding.

Comment: @Ben I said to change the `xtics` and `ytics` options, not `xrange` and `yrange`. Please see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Aha, indeed you did. That works! Thank you. It doesn't seem possible to prevent the last x tic from being printed, since the range is dynamic (ending with \*) and I can't do `*-1` or just `-1`. But at least I can get rid of the x=-1, y=-1, and y=11 tics.

Comment: @Ben You could find the maximum x value in your data set using [`List::Util::max`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#$num-=-max-@list) and set the xtics `end` property based on that, but that seems like a lot of extra work for little gain.

Comment: @Ben You could also try using `GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN` like in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13583689/176646). Unfortunately, you can't access `GPVAL_*` variables until after a plot has been created, so I think you would have to set your tic options using `$chart->set(...)` *after* calling `$chart->plot2d(...)`. Probably not ideal, but another option to consider.