# gnuplot: connecting last to first point in polar plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file like

```
0 8.4
60 7.5
120 8.9
180 9.2
240 8.3
300 6.9
```

My gnuplot script looks this way:

```
unset xtics
unset ytics
set polar
set angle degrees
set rrange [0:10]
set rtics 2
set grid polar
set size square
p 'data.txt' u 1:2 w lp
```

My problem is that I want the first and last data point to be connected by the line. I get the expected result if I repeat the first point in my data file again at the end of the file like:

```
0 8.4
60 7.5
120 8.9
180 9.2
240 8.3
300 6.9
0 8.4
```

Ist this the only way to get the expected result? I'm asking because my real file has a lot of data-sets which I reference by the gnuplot `index` command like `p 'data.txt' index 1276 u 1:2 w lp` and always duplicating the first data point again at the end at each block is quite annoying.

Comment: something like "set style fill transparent solid 0; plot "data" w filledcurves closed" should do the trick, only the line around the filled area does not close. Seems like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to connect the first and last point by doing a second plot with only those two points.

Using the syntax every (check `help plot every`), you can plot only the first point (number 0) and last point (number N)
with :

`every N::0::N`

In the example you gave, the line 9 should be modified as follow :

```
p 'data.txt' u 1:2 w lp ls 1, 'data.txt' u 1:2 ev 5::0::5 w lp ls 1 noti
```

A first flaw in this solution is you have to specify the style of the second line to ensure it looks like the first one, and does not appear in the keys (hence the `ls 1` and `noti`).

The second flaw is you need to know the number of points in your block. It can be obtained in gnuplot using the `stats` syntax, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580236/gnuplot-max-and-min-values-in-a-range). For your example, I would use it on the column 0 (for the points numbers) as follows :

```
stats 'data.txt' u 0
N = STATS_max
```