# I can't superpose these two plots together

Tags: gnuplot

I have no errors when I load in gnuplot a file containing only instructions for the first plot (see below) or a file containing only instructions for the second plot. 
However, combining the two set of instructions in one file (so I can superpose the plots), I have this gnuplot error message : `"myFile.gnu", line 28: undefined variable: t` where myFile.gnu has the entire content FIRST PLOT + SECOND PLOT below.

I can't find which option(s) of the first plot is (are) in conflict with the second plot. Any idea ?

```
# FIRST PLOT
set term x11 size 700,700
set autoscale
unset log
set size square 1,1
set grid
set autoscale fix
set title 'Free Energy (kcal/mol)'
set xlabel 'phi'
set ylabel 'psi'
unset key
set cblabel
set cntrparam levels incr 0,2,20
set pm3d map interpolate 1,1
set style increment userstyles
load 'analysis/RdYlBu.pal'
set contour
set style line 1 lc rgb "dark-blue"
unset clabel
set dgrid3d
splot 'file.dat' u 1:2:3 lc rgb 'black'

# SECOND PLOT
set parametric
set trange [-pi:pi]
x1(t)=-1.3+1.5*cos(t)
y1(t)=1.5+0.9*sin(t)
replot x1(t),y1(t)
theta1=2.2
replot x1(t)*cos(theta1)-y1(t)*sin(theta1)-1.55,x1(t)*sin(theta1)+y1(t)*cos(theta1)+3.75 title 'ellipse1'
x2(t)=1+0.4*cos(t)
y2(t)=-0.7+0.8*sin(t)
replot x2(t),y2(t)
theta2=0
replot x2(t)*cos(theta2)-y2(t)*sin(theta2)+0.2,x2(t)*sin(theta2)+y2(t)*cos(theta2)-0.7 title 'ellipse2'
```

Comment: Your first file does an `splot`, so that the `replot` in the second file also calls an `splot`. And that command knows `u` and `v` as dummy variables in parametric mode.

Comment: I put u,v instead of t in all the functions I created, but I get a  `parametric function not fully specified` error.

Comment: Becausr `splot` requires three functions in parametric mode

Comment: Well is there anyway to overlap the two plots with gnuplot or do I have to go on with gimp or something ?

Comment: I tried the mutliplot option of gnuplot. Result : first plot is inside second plot like a square in a bigger square.

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but you mix together a quite complex script. And without having data to test it is all about guessing...

Comment: As said by @Christoph you are mixing 2d and 3d plot. To fix that error (`parametric function not fully specified`) you can use `replot x1(u),y1(u),0` for example. I suppose you cannot have in the same time ad dummy variable _x,y_ and _u,v_. Try to generate your `pm3d` without border, margin... and with the dimensions of the range you will use in the next plot, then you can use it as [background for the second plot](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.ru/2011/09/gnuplot-background-image.html). Maybe check [this page too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13583689/3569208)

Comment: I think I'd go with gimp or so ...

Answer (score 0):

Havent tried it, but this idea could work. Do:

```
set multiplot
```

above the first scrip. After first script, append

```
unset
```

of all `set`s. Below that, append:

```
set origin 0,0
set size 1,1
```

and below this, append the second script. Then append

```
set multiplot
```

(not an answear, i know, but woulden't have been a beautiful comment)